# M2.2: Failed to set ini option

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.2

I feel this ought to be a simple fix, but I am not finding any straightforward solutions. Initially I thought it was a permissions thing, but the config files reflect the correct username and password. I'm stumped.

#### Error Message

> ### There was an Error Processing Your Request
>
> Failed to set ini option "session.save_handler" to value "files".

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Install a fresh copy of Magento 2.2.4 via GoDaddy's cPanel Installatron.
2. Go to anywhere in the Magento directory. This message apears.

#### Expected result

1. The homepage or a login screen. No error message.

#### Actual result

1. Error message appears wherever in the Magento directory you go.

#### Environment

- **Magento 2.2.4** (auto-updated from v.2.2.3 a couple weeks before the issue appeared.)
- Plain Magento. **No additional extensions, plugins or addons**, aside from what already comes packaged with the Magento 2.2.4 install.
- **Linux**. GoDaddy Hosted. cPanel. 2GB RAM. 2 CPUs.
- Magento installed in directory **/shop/**
- **SSL Certificate** in use.
- Magento Base URL (both Secured and Unsecured) are set like: 
  http**s**://**www**.example.com/**shop/** 
  (note the "s" in "https", the "www." subdomain, the directory "shop", and the trailing forward-slash)
- **htaccess** redirects any non-WWW traffic to www subdomain.
- **PHP 7.1.17** (All required extensions installed and functioning)
- **MySQL 5.6.39**

#### Preconditions

- The site was running perfectly at version 2.2.3 for three weeks.
- The auto-update to 2.2.4 broke my site instantly... But I followed some safe-sounding forum solutions to fix it.
- Site ran perfectly again as ver. 2.2.4 for another two weeks but then suddenly, last week, I couldn't log in anymore, and other parts of the site began malfunctioning as well.
- Note: As the site was working fine, no changes were made to the code for weeks. The issue occurred *seemingly* on its own.
- I followed several forum remedies (rolling back each time they didn't work before trying a new "solution"), but no suggestions worked worked.
- In defeat, I reset my server completely, installed a FRESH copy of Magento 2.2.4 (via GoDaddy's "Installatron" again) (thus also skipping v2.2.3 altogether this time)
  -Problem resurfaced with the same error message right away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Magento 2 tries to set the value of some configuration options in ***initIniOptions()*** function of **SessionManager** class (**/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php**), like '*session.save_handler*'; in same system this operation is not allowed.

This problem is solved in Magento 2.3 version so the solution to your problem is temporarily to overwrite ***initIniOptions()*** function.
See here: [Magento 2.3 SessionManager.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Session/SessionManager.php)